# How to programmatically check bluetooth speaker is connected to rpi3?

Tags: raspbian-jessie, bluetooth, python-3, docker

I am trying to detect if my bluetooth speaker is connected to my rpi3 with my python code, executing this command

```
status = subprocess.call('ls /dev/input/event0 2>/dev/null', shell=True)
```

if the directory /dev/input/event0 exists, then it will pass the check. However, the directory is never created even after I connect my bluetooth speaker and have already tested it by playing smth from it. Below is the output when I run the command `ls /dev/input`

[image]

How else can I check if the speaker is connected using a python script?

- rpi3 os version: jessie
- python: python 3.4

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking at doing something similar, but I've not actually gotten around to trying it... and so you have a chance to be a true pioneer here :) In addition, [this is not the only solution, or even the best one, but it's the one I'm going to try.](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=164400) Note that the steps to install the dependencies and get the actual code are embedded in this post from Nov, 2016.